# Every 4th sunday at 6:45am my web server goes down because of apc_mmap error

Tags: apache-2.2, alternative-php-cache

> PHP Fatal error: PHP Startup: apc_mmap: mmap failed: in Unknown on line 0
>
> [Sun Aug 11 06:45:16 2013] [notice] seg fault or similar nasty error detected in the parent process

The system (Ubuntu 12.04.2) was at 18% of total memory and APC was using 32% of apc.shm_size, so it wasn't for lack of memory. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

I also have these two entries at the same time in syslog

> Aug 11 06:45:16 ip-10-145-209-85 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="718" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
>
> Aug 11 06:45:16 ip-10-145-209-85 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="718" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed

Comment: Looks like logrotation is taking place?

Comment: Ok... "every 4th sunday"... maybe not logrotation after all. What does the crontab contain?

Comment: Crontab does not contain anything for that time, but the logs do in fact rotate at that exact time. Why would that mess with APC, and what could I do to fix?

Comment: Well if the logs rotate then there is something either in the user's crontab (/var/spool/cron.../) or the system crontabs (/etc/crontab, /etc/cron.d/, /etc/cron.something). I suppose if apc crashes at that moment it doesn't like when logfiles are moved away, maybe you also need to give a signal to APC just like rsyslog gets a signal. If I were you I would investigate in that direction (APC/logrotation).

Answer (score 1):

let's take closer look:

```
PHP Fatal error: PHP Startup: apc_mmap: mmap failed: in Unknown on line 0
```

First keyword is "**PHP Startup**". This means that process is reloaded/restarted/respawn etc. But service couldn't start. Reason for respawn? There are lot of them. I'm quite sure there is nothing to do with the cron and logrotation.

Second keyword is "**apc_mmap: mmap failed**". I guess there is not enough shared memory.

Check `sysctl -a|grep shmmax`. Tune it to reasonable maximum.

Please update post with apc configuration from php.ini.

Comment: The system has 15GB of memory and was at 40% when apache crashed, here are some settings:

kernel.shmmax = 15032385536 
apc.shm_size=5G 
apc.ttl=86400 
apc.shm_segments=1 
apc.max_file_size=10M 
apc.rfc1867 = On

Comment: hm... memory_limit ?

Comment: memory_limit = 128M

Comment: Distro? Package versions? any "segfaults" in /var/log/syslog?

Comment: I think I found the cause. I ran out of ionodes in my session folder. Whenever that limit is reached by sunday morning, the server crashes.